# How to logically create a Graph?

Tags: java

I have a filter system where a user can choose between 8 arguments, and each argument can be null or not null. At the end of each path I need to call a method only with the arguments which are not null. How can I do it ?

If I use this scheme, it will be so large…

```
if (arg1 ==true){
  if (args2 == true){
    if(arg3 == true) {
       do(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
     else{
        do(arg1, arg2);
        }
  }
    else {
       do(arg1);
      }
 }
else {
do();
}
```

Comment: You may implement just one do method with do(String ... args) syntax,and you can just call one time it,and then arrange inside this method.

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate those arguments into one object . then pass the object created by you into the same method and deal with your problem in this method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be comparing the args with `null`, rather than `true`.

If I were you, I would reconsider the design. Passing in lots of nulls is not a normal way to write Java code and makes the API and its implementation complicated.

If the arguments are all of the same type then you might be able to use varargs for the parameters. Otherwise, the [Builder design pattern](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html) might be useful to build up an object with reasonable defaults for missing arguments.